# Reflection on JS promise object to retrieve list of then/catch calls

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to create a custom Promise class in which I can define a default rejection handler, but only if the promise does not already have a `catch` on it. So is there a way I can list how many times has `catch` been called on a given promise?

**Edit**: Here's my first stab at it, which doesn't fully work yet:

```js
class ApiPromise extends Promise {
  catch(callback, keepDefault = false) {
    if (!keepDefault) this._defaultCatch = false
    super.catch(callback)
    return this
  }

  defaultCatch(callback) {
    this._defaultCatch = callback
    this.catch(e => {
      if (this._defaultCatch) return this._defaultCatch(e)
      return e
    }, true)
    return this
  }
}

// This works as expected (defaultCatch not called):
new ApiPromise(() => { throw 'test' })
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('defaultCatch') })
  .catch(e => { console.log('catch overridden'); return e })

// This causes an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
new ApiPromise(() => { throw 'test' })
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('defaultCatch') })
  .catch(e => { console.log('catch overridden'); return e })
  .then(e => { console.log('then'); return e })

// And this calls the `defaultCatch`, which I didn't expect:
new ApiPromise(() => { throw 'test' })
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('defaultCatch') })
  .then(e => { console.log('then'); return e })
  .catch(e => { console.log('catch overridden'); return e })
```

The purpose of this approach is so certain errors are handled a certain way, while allowing to override such behavior.

Comment: Well if you have a custom `Promise` class, surely you will also have a custom `then` method that knows when it has been called?

Comment: That said, default rejection handlers are a pretty bad idea. You never know where your error propagates and how it should be handled.

Comment: The original JS promises implementation would be one place to start: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: What's the purpose of this default error handler? Logging/not logging as an error, or resolving to a fallback value? null? or how else do you define which Promise in the tree should resolve to which default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the idea correctly, you should make the default catch handler such *as if* it were attached at the very end of the promise chain, as a normal `catch` handler. As promises can have multiple `then` calls, they form together an asynchronous tree of promise chains, and so you would have to know which are the *leaves* of that tree, so you can (inside your implementation) attach a `catch` handler that will perform the default action.

So if you have something like this:

```
let p = new ApiPromise(() => { throw 'test' })
           .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('defaultCatch') });
p.then(() => 1);
p.then(() => 2);
```

...you would want it to *behave* as if you had written this:

```
let p = new ApiPromise(() => { throw 'test' });
p.then(() => 1).catch(() => { console.log('defaultCatch') });
p.then(() => 2).catch(() => { console.log('defaultCatch') });
```

You could do that as follows:

```js
class ApiPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super(executor);
        this._isLeaf = true;
        this._defaultOnReject = null;
    }
    defaultCatch(onReject) {
        this._defaultOnReject = onReject;
        super.then(null, err => this._isLeaf && this._defaultOnReject(err));
        return this;
    }
    then(onFulfill, onReject) {
        // It is not needed to override the `catch` method, as according to ECMAScript
        // specification, `catch()` will translate to a call to the `then` method. 
        let apiPromise = super.then(onFulfill, onReject);
        console.assert(apiPromise instanceof ApiPromise);
        // copy defaultCatch handler reference down the promise chain
        if (this._defaultOnReject) apiPromise.defaultCatch(this._defaultOnReject);
        this._isLeaf = false;
        return apiPromise;
    }
}

// Examples from the question:
new ApiPromise(() => { throw new Error('1. error') })
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('1. defaultCatch') })
  .catch(e => { console.log('1. catch overridden'); return e });

new ApiPromise(() => { throw new Error('2. error') })
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('2. defaultCatch') })
  .catch(e => { console.log('2. catch overridden'); return e })
  .then(e => { console.log('2. then'); return e });

new ApiPromise(() => { throw new Error('3. error') })
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('3. defaultCatch') })
  .then(e => { console.log('3. then'); return e })
  .catch(e => { console.log('3. catch overridden'); return e });

// Some more examples
// 4. no catch at all
new ApiPromise(() => { throw new Error('4. error') })
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('4. defaultCatch') });

// 5. no catch, and the deeper defaultCatch will still take care of it
new ApiPromise(() => { throw new Error('5. error') })
  .then(v => 1)
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('5. defaultCatch') });
  
// 6. no catch, and we throw only after defaultCatch is set
new ApiPromise(resolve => resolve(1))
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('6. defaultCatch') })
  .then(v => 1)
  .then(() => { throw new Error('6. error') });

// 7. A split into 2 promise chains
let p = new ApiPromise((resolve) => resolve(1))
        .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('7. defaultCatch') })
p.then(v => 1)
 .catch(e => { console.log('7. catch overridden'); return e; });
 
p.then(v => 2)
 .then(v => { throw new Error('7. error') }); // no catch => default

// 8. throw after catch, captured by default
new ApiPromise((resolve) => resolve(1))
  .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('8. defaultCatch') })
  .catch(e => { console.log('8. catch overridden'); return e; })
  .then(() => { throw new Error('8. error') });

// 9. A split into 2 promise chains, default is not applicable
let q = new ApiPromise((resolve) => resolve(1))
q.then(v => 1)
 .defaultCatch(() => { console.log('9. defaultCatch') })
 .catch(e => { console.log('9. catch overridden'); return e; });
 
q.then(v => 2)
 .then(v => { throw new Error('9. error') }); // no catch, no default => uncaught!

// 10. Error in defaultCatch callback
new ApiPromise((resolve) => resolve(1))
 .defaultCatch(() => { throw new Error('10. error in defaultCatch') })
 .then(v => { throw new Error('1. causing error') });

// 11. When `then` callback returns an ApiPromise
new ApiPromise(resolve => resolve(1))
    .defaultCatch(() => { console.log("11. defaultCatch") })
    .then(() => new ApiPromise(resolve => resolve(2)))
    .then(() => { throw new Error("11. error") })
    .then(() => console.log("11. then"));
```

This snippet runs the three examples you have given, and it has a few more. Note that the Stack Snippet virtual console does not display the "uncaught promise rejections" which are intended to occur with tests number 9 and 10. But you can see them in the browser's real console.

### Explanations

The nice thing about `Promise` (and many other native constructors) is that when a prototype method needs to create a new instance, it will look up which constructor to use for that. If you use `extends`, then that default is not the original constructor (`Promise` in this case), but the derived constructor (`ApiPromise` in this case). Concretely, when this implementation executes `super.then`, we get back an `ApiPromise` instance, not a pure `Promise` instance. This is exactly what is needed in the overridden `then` implementation.

The core of the logic of this implementation is found in the `super.then` callback defined in the `defaultCatch` method. Here it listens to a rejection. It was tempting to write `super.catch` there, but that would in turn call `then` on the instance, and since this implementation overrides the `then` method, we would actually not call the original `Promise` implementation, and fall into an infinite recursion trap. By using the second argument of `super.then` we avoid this, and truly call the native `then` implementation.

This callback to `super.then` (i.e. `catch` really) does not do anything if it sees that the current promise is not the last one in the chain. In that case we just want the normal chaining (of the rejection) to proceed as it would normally do. If however, the current promise is a leaf, then the default handler is called and its return value becomes the resolution of the current (leaf) promise. If there is no default catch handler defined, then the behaviour will be standard, and the rejection will trigger the environment's "uncaught promise rejection" exception.

Notice that the `then` method implementation takes care of distributing the default catch handler (if there is one) to the next(s) in the promise chain, by again calling `defaultCatch` on those new promises. Also, it takes care of unflagging the current promise as a leaf, as this `then` call effectively makes it an "internal node" in the promise chain. The promise that is returned by `then` is a new promise for which the `ApiPromise` constructor has been executed, and so it has the leaf-mark.

This solution would need to be extended to have replacements for `Promise` static methods, such as `Promise.resolve`, `Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, ...etc.

Comment: This. Thanks for writing up this elaborate answer. Notice that you could avoid the `_returnApiPromise` workaround if you put the `super.then(null, err => { if (this._isLeaf) return this._defaultOnReject(err); });` inside the `defaultCatch()` method. This also fixed the unhandled rejection stack trace as it is the original promise that is unhandled (until installing the default handler).

Comment: And while all of this works fine in the presented examples, as soon as you use promise chaining (like `normalPromise.then(() => { …; return apiPromiseThing(); })` or `async function() { …; await apiPromiseThing(); … }`) the whole pattern breaks down since the outer promise is not an `ApiPromise` any more and no default handler will ever get called. So, still a bad idea…

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi, I took your insight and removed the `_returnApiPromise` workaround. I just had to call `defaultCatch` again on the chained promises. As to your second comment, I am sure it will break down somewhere if non-ApiPromises get in the way. I did add one more test (11), which still works, but maybe I didn't push far enough ;-)

Comment: I was referring to the case where the `.defaultCatch` was called on the *inner* apiPromise - it's hard to propagate that in `ApiPromise.resolve(1).then(() => someApiPromise().defaultCatch(…)).…` and impossible to propagate in `Promise.resolve(1).then(() => someApiPromise().defaultCatch(…)).…`. Although the concept of a "default rejection handler" doesn't even really make sense in that context, what if the outer chain has its own default handler…

Comment: Ah, yes, in that scenario -- where `defaultCatch` would be called within a `then` callback -- I wouldn't really know what the expected behaviour would be. It seems like whatever choice you would make (for desired behaviour), it would lead to surprising results in other constructs.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I'm aware of the pitfalls, but usage of this class would be in a very contained fashion, allowing for a lot more concise code. However it seems it's gonna be more complex to implement that might warrant the benefit, so I will re-evaluate.